# simple question on POKER HAND probiblity {full house}

Tags: probability-theory

So I have a question about the probability of having a full house in a poker hands (5 cards), from a standard deck of cards (52).

The solution is

```
13C1 x 12C1  x [4C3 x 4C2]   x 1/(52C5)
```

For 4C3 x4C2, I understand what it means. 
For the first term: 13C1 x 12C1, does this multiplication assumes the ordering such that Kings, Ace in this order is different from Ace, King?
if that is the case, should we also divide 2! to make to not order dependent????

Comment: What's a full house?

Comment: The reason why order matters is that Aces over Kings (3 aces and 2 kings) is a different hand (in poker) than Kings over aces (3 kings and 2 aces).

Comment: For two pairs we have to divide, since two Kings and two $7$'s is the same as two $7$'s and two Kings. But three Kings and two $7$'s is not the same as three $7$'s and two Kings.

Comment: "An explanation of the formula: there are 13 ranks (ace through king), and four of each rank (one per suit), in the standard 52-card deck. Denominator: we express choosing 5 cards out of the 52 cards in the deck. Numerator: first we multiply the number of ways to choose 1 rank out of the 13 ranks, then 3 cards out of 4 of that chosen rank. Second, we choose 1 out of 12 remaining ranks, and choose 2 cards out of 4 from that rank." : from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands#Full_house

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick the rank that appears as triple: $13\choose 1$

Pick a *different* rank that appears as pair: $12\choose 1$

Pick the three suits that occur in the triple: $4\choose 3$

Picj the two colours that occur in the pair: $4\choose 2$.

Note that full house with three aces and two kings is different from three kings and two aces.